# TimeBasedRollingPolicy failed to rollover logfiles yesterday, but I see no RolloverFailure?

Tags: logback

I have an appender configured like...

```
<appender name="DAILY_ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
  <File>logs/dm.log</File>
  <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    <FileNamePattern>logs/dm.%d{yyyyMMdd}.log</FileNamePattern>
  </rollingPolicy>
  <encoder>
    <pattern>%m%n</pattern>
  </encoder>
</appender>
...
<root level="info">
  <appender-ref ref="DAILY_ROLLING" />
  <appender-ref ref="SYSLOG" />
</root>
```

...which typically has the effect of logging current data to the dm.log file and everyday at midnight rolling over the dm.log into a file named for the date, dm.20130205.log.  Yesterday, however, for the first time ever, this rollover did not occur.  My dm.log file now has 2 days worth of data and I am wondering what went wrong?  I expected to find a RolloverFailure or some indication of what went wrong to be laying in the dm.log file but there is nothing there.

Where do I look to figure out what went wrong in logback?  I have never seen this mechanism fail in either logback or log4j.

Comment: I see no evidence of application restart in the logfile, which is the only reason I can think of for logback missing the day rollover.

Comment: This problem is getting worse for me, the silence both hear and on the logback-user mailing list is unsettling.  This has something to do with our NAS, but I don't know what.  Lack of stderr/stdout logging isn't helping here either.  I'm in the dark...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
-Dlogback.statusListenerClass=ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnConsoleStatusListener
```

Or event implementing your own status listener. Then try configuring a file roll every 10 seconds, in a test system, and leave it to soak test.

It might well be a NAS issue.  We've had our NAS fail silently in hard to detect ways.  Also if the file roll in is in the middle of the night, and it's an overnight batch processing system then the NAS load can be high at that time.

What version of logback are you using?

Edit: A the rollover could be skipped if the rename of the file fails.  In my own code I would retry this, but in RenameUtil.rename() logback will just warn you via the status listener.

Comment: We are 1.0.9 logback and, indeed, the app servers that are now failing are all logging to a NAS mount.  I'll see what I can see with the OnConsoleStatusListener.  The bad news, our silly jetty "optimized" startup script just swallows stderr/stdout.  Sigh.

Comment: At the end of the day it was, indeed, the rollover failing because of permissions problems.  We fixed the permissions and the rollovers picked right up where they left off.